# Let I denote the unit interval $[0, 1].$ Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: general-topology

Let $B := \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
: x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$be the closed ball in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with center at the origin.
Let I denote the unit interval $[0, 1].$ Which of the following statements are true?

Which of the following statements are true?

$(a)$ There exists a continuous function $f : B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is one-one

$(b)$ There exists a continuous function $f : B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is onto.

$(c)$ There exists a continuous function $f : B \rightarrow I × I$ which is one-one.

$(d)$ There exists a continuous function $f : B \rightarrow I × I$ which is onto.

I thinks  none  of  option will be correct

option $a)$ and option $b)$ is false   Just  using the   logics  of compactness, that is $\mathbb{R}$ is not compacts
option c) and option d) is false  just using  the logic of connectedness  that is  $B-\{0\}$ is not connected but $I × I-\{0\}$ is connectedness

Is  my logics  is correct or not ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: why does compactness of $B$ help in (a)?  $f$ is not onto there.  Also, $B-\{0\}$ is certainly connected.

Comment: @Randall B is  a circle   , cut the circle   it will disconnect

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.  $B$ is a solid disk.  If you poke a hole in a disk it is still connected.

Comment: oh,!    ya  ...i got it now  @Randall

Comment: @Randall that mean option $ c) $and option $d$ is correct?

Comment: I don't know....

Comment: @Randall      hint/signal is enough for a wise man!!!!

Comment: @Randall compactness does help if you know dimension theory too: if $f: B \to \mathbb{R}$ were continuous and 1-1, $f[B]$ would be homeomorphic to $B$ by compactness. But $\dim f[B] \le 1$ while $\dim B=2$. Bit overkill though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option a) is false because we cannot even find such a map from $S^1$, the unit circle by the simplest version of Borsuk-Ulam: there are already points $x$ and $-x$ on the boundary of $B$ that have the same value.

Option b) is indeed most easily disproved by noting that $f[B]$ is compact and the reals are not.

Options c) and d) are true: $B$ is homeomorphic to $ I \times I$, as is well-known. A homeomorphism will fulfill both. Note that $B\setminus\{0\}$ is actually connected so your proposed argument doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

**(a) is false**

As $B$ is a compact and $f$ is continuous, $f$ is an homeomorphism from the compact $B$ to $f[B]$. As $B$ is connected, $f[B]$ is also connected and is therefore an interval. However $B\setminus \{0\}$ is connected and $f[B\setminus \{0\}]$ cannot be connected. That can’t be as $f$ is an homeomorphism.

**(b) is false**

The image of the compact $B$ must be compact and $\mathbb R$ isn’t.

**(c) and (d) are true**

Consider the application that transform a ray of the unit ball into the line segment joining the origin of $B$ to the point of square aligned with the original ray.